# Sbt, analyse dependency and plugins problems, tips needed

Tags: sbt, dependency-management

I have a multi-module Sbt project who works fine. However yesterday I have added a plugin who cause many troubles.
First it introduced `sbt.IncompatiblePluginsException`, I had to disabled each plugins to detect wich one was in conflict and then search trough the two sources to guess the dependency in conflict so that I can finaly solve it with a `dependencyOverrides`.

The build run fine on my machine but on my CI server it is awfully slow (> 40' instead of 10) I think it is because it download a lot of dependencies. Maybe can I naively disable the new plugin but It would like to learn techniques to clean my dependency tree and solve such conflict problems efficiently.

Did you have some tips and tools that I can use to view who is using so much dependencies and how to solve it. But also how detect which tasks is taking so much time.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My CI uses an old sbt version (I'm managing that). But it seems that since 0.13.7 when a dependency is unresolved sbt guess the path https://www.typesafe.com/blog/improved-dependency-management-with-sbt-0137. That's already a good thing